# Liquibase Rollback sql script is being run when performing update

Tags: sql, liquibase

I have rollback scripts and changeset scripts in same file. However, when I perform `liquibase update`, the database migrates successfully but the `users` table is dropped. How can I fix the error? I want to keep rollback scripts and changeset in the same file.

```sql
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset Ariel:20231120_000002
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- rollback for changeset Ariel:20231120_000002
-- liquibase formatted sql
DROP TABLE users;
```

Similarly, if I try to rollback I get the below error. I'm not sure why liquibase is not recognizing the rollback properly. How can I fix it?

````bash
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Liquibase does not support automatic rollback generation for raw sql changes (did you mean to specify keyword "empty" to ignore rolling back this change?)

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rollback without "for changeset ..."?

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset Ariel:20231120_000002
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
-- rollback DROP TABLE users;
```